# EJB 3.1 | Error calling remote session bean via JNDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, jndi

I'm trying to call a simple stateless session bean from a Java SE (Simple class).

**Here's my bean**

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 *
 * @author MMRUser
 */
@Stateless
public class CapitalBean implements CapitalBeanRemote {

    public String greetingsEjb(String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

**Remote interface**

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

/**
 *
 * @author MMRUser
 */
@Remote
public interface CapitalBeanRemote {

    public String greetingsEjb(String name);
}
```

From my client side I used stand-alone java class to call the session bean using JNDI as follows

```
import ejb.CapitalBeanRemote;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

/**
 *
 * @author MMRUser
 */
public class CallEjbClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            CapitalBeanRemote bean = (CapitalBeanRemote)
            context.lookup("java:global/CapitalApplication/CapitalBean");
            context.close();
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

Things are pretty straight forward, but when I ran this application I'm getting an exception saying

```
avax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CapitalBean not found
```

I'm using Glassfish 3.1.1 as my application server and Netbeans 7.0.1 as my IDE. Already added these jar files to my classpath:

**CapitalApplication-ejb.jar**

**appserv-rt.jar**

**gf-client.jar**

I also tried different JNDI naming conventions like:

java:global/CapitalApplication!ejb.CapitalBean

but nothing seems to work here.

Here's the full stack trace

```
run:
Nov 20, 2011 6:14:58 PM com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityMechanismSelector postConstruct
SEVERE: IIOP1005: An exception has occured in the ejb security initialization.
org.jvnet.hk2.component.ComponentException: injection failed on org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.invHandlers with class [Lorg.glassfish.api.invocation.ComponentInvocationHandler;
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.error_injectionException(InjectionManager.java:277)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:159)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByContract(Habitat.java:1042)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getComponent(Habitat.java:777)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityMechanismSelector.postConstruct(SecurityMechanismSelector.java:166)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1048)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1029)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getComponentInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:159)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:90)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:141)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1048)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1029)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getComponent(Habitat.java:779)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.Lookups._getSecurityContextUtil(Lookups.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.Lookups.getSecurityContextUtil(Lookups.java:92)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor.<init>(SecClientRequestInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.appclient.AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.getClientInterceptorInstance(AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.appclient.AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.createClientRequestInterceptor(AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBInitializer.post_init(GlassFishORBInitializer.java:132)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.postInitORBInitializers(PIHandlerImpl.java:915)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.initialize(PIHandlerImpl.java:265)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:704)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:691)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:581)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at firstjavaapp.CallEjbClass.main(CallEjbClass.java:21)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hk2.component.ComponentException: Failed to create class com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.create(ConstructorCreator.java:71)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:80)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat$5.get(Habitat.java:701)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:188)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getArrayInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:113)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:81)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:141)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/resource/ResourceException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.create(ConstructorCreator.java:65)
    ... 65 more

javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:global/CapitalApplication/CapitalBean' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CapitalBean not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at firstjavaapp.CallEjbClass.main(CallEjbClass.java:21)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: CapitalBean not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:219)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(RemoteSerialContextProviderImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie.dispatchToMethod(ReflectiveTie.java:144)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.ReflectiveTie._invoke(ReflectiveTie.java:174)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:528)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:199)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

**UPDATE**

Tried changing the JNDI naming convention to this:

```
java:global/CapitalApplication/CapitalApplication-ejb/CapitalBean!ejb.CapitalBeanRemote
```

and now I'm getting a different exception:

```
run:
Nov 20, 2011 7:08:52 PM com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityMechanismSelector postConstruct
SEVERE: IIOP1005: An exception has occured in the ejb security initialization.
org.jvnet.hk2.component.ComponentException: injection failed on org.glassfish.api.invocation.InvocationManagerImpl.invHandlers with class [Lorg.glassfish.api.invocation.ComponentInvocationHandler;
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.error_injectionException(InjectionManager.java:277)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:159)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByContract(Habitat.java:1042)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getComponent(Habitat.java:777)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecurityMechanismSelector.postConstruct(SecurityMechanismSelector.java:166)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1048)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1029)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getComponentInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:159)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:90)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:141)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getBy(Habitat.java:1048)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getByType(Habitat.java:1029)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat.getComponent(Habitat.java:779)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.Lookups._getSecurityContextUtil(Lookups.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.Lookups.getSecurityContextUtil(Lookups.java:92)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecClientRequestInterceptor.<init>(SecClientRequestInterceptor.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.appclient.AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.getClientInterceptorInstance(AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.appclient.AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.createClientRequestInterceptor(AppclientIIOPInterceptorFactory.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBInitializer.post_init(GlassFishORBInitializer.java:132)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.postInitORBInitializers(PIHandlerImpl.java:915)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.initialize(PIHandlerImpl.java:265)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.postInit(ORBImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.set_parameters(ORBImpl.java:704)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl.setParameters(ORBImpl.java:691)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.osgi.ORBFactory.initialize(ORBFactory.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.initORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:581)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBManager.getORB(GlassFishORBManager.java:263)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.impl.GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.createORB(GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.java:93)
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at firstjavaapp.CallEjbClass.main(CallEjbClass.java:20)
Caused by: org.jvnet.hk2.component.ComponentException: Failed to create class com.sun.enterprise.resource.pool.PoolManagerImpl
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.create(ConstructorCreator.java:71)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:80)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:76)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.Habitat$5.get(Habitat.java:701)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:358)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(AbstractCollection.java:188)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getArrayInjectValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:113)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.InjectInjectionResolver.getValue(InjectInjectionResolver.java:81)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.component.InjectionManager.inject(InjectionManager.java:141)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/resource/ResourceException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.create(ConstructorCreator.java:65)
    ... 65 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/ejb/RemoveException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2562)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2572)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2572)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1427)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLTypesUtil.validateRemoteInterface(IDLTypesUtil.java:96)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.<init>(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:226)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.<init>(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:65)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl$2.run(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl$2.run(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.IDLNameTranslatorImpl.get(IDLNameTranslatorImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl$ClassDataImpl.<init>(PresentationManagerImpl.java:153)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl$1.lookup(PresentationManagerImpl.java:103)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl$1.lookup(PresentationManagerImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.spi.orbutil.misc.WeakCache.get(WeakCache.java:114)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.PresentationManagerImpl.getClassData(PresentationManagerImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubFactoryFactoryDynamicBase.createStubFactory(StubFactoryFactoryDynamicBase.java:91)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.util.Utility.loadStub(Utility.java:835)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:252)
    at javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject.narrow(PortableRemoteObject.java:153)
    at com.sun.ejb.EJBUtils.lookupRemote30BusinessObject(EJBUtils.java:406)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(RemoteBusinessObjectFactory.java:75)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:514)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at firstjavaapp.CallEjbClass.main(CallEjbClass.java:20)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: When the Glassfish starts, doesn't it show you what JNDI names are assigned to EJBs?

Comment: It does "java:global/CapitalApplication/CapitalApplication-ejb/CapitalBean!ejb.CapitalBeanRemote"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and just found the [solution here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/554447/EJB-JEE/java/cannot-retrieve-stateless-bean-JNDI).

Check the final post. It seems that the key is the order of the JAR files in the classpath. Make sure you include gf-client.jar before javaee-api-6.0.jar.

Comment: The problem was that Netbeans initially added the javaee-api-6.0.jar when a project is creating so the order get messed up every time.