# MultiException and PerseistenceException in javaEE with Beans

Tags: jsp, javabeans, glassfish-4, java-ee-7, netbeans-8

I know there are a lot of threads to this topic, but after searching for ~10 hours without a solution I will ask in a new thread.
I got two projects not working (properly).
I use Windows 8.1 64 bit with a clean jre/jdk 8 and javaee7. I have a glassfish 4 server and netbeans 8.
When I say my server log is empty than I mean the server domain log file found in "%glassgish4%\glassfish\domains\domain1\log".
My projects are simple enterprise-applications with JavaBeans.
My first problem is a multiexception in a simple remote method invocation via session-beans. 
I created the enterprise-application-project and a normal client (java) project to hold the remote interface.  The client calls a simple method to add two numbers.
The project-structure can be seen here:
[Project-Structure](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23480543/structure1.png.html)

The interface in the client-application can bee seen here:
[NeueSessionBeanRemote](http://pastebin.com/qQT2gRs8)

The interface implementation in the enterprise-application is this one:
[Interface-Implementation](http://pastebin.com/JYRbjLNj)

And here is the main-method from client-application:
[main-method](http://pastebin.com/Yey0Nrix)

The netbeans error output is here:
[netbeans errror output](http://pastebin.com/M0Wx0qzH)

The server log is empty (just a succes notification from deploying the enterprise application project).

Well this was the first problem. Now I will tell you about the second.
It is a project allowing to enter customer information in a jsp form and inserting them into a database (travel agency).

This is the structure:
[second project structure](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23480574/structure2.png.html)

I copied the class "Kunde" to the client-application because the RemoteInterface did not know "Kunde".
Well this is my RemoteInterface "Reisebuero2Remote":
[Reisebuero2Interface](http://pastebin.com/0ausgB5S)

I won't show the client main method, because it is empty ;)
The interface-implementation looks like this:
[interface-implementation](http://pastebin.com/Kv3ki7xu)
The "Kunde" looks like that:
[Kunde](http://pastebin.com/ngzthMN7)

Because the web implementation is simple html I will only show you the jsp file:
[jsp file](http://pastebin.com/dixicrUs)

And here is my probelm I can't even build the enterprise-application:
[error at building](http://pastebin.com/1iHFwGqF)

My server log is empty again.
If you need further information I will try to provide them.
Thank you very much for your support.

---

Edit:
Content of pom.xml from folder: C:\Program Files\glassfish-4\glassfish\lib\install\applications__admingui\META-INF\maven\org.glassfish.main.admingui\war
//Removed
POM.XML

Search Result for pom.xml in Project-Folder:
[Search-Result](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23483701/search.png.html)
Context-Menu on project in Netbeans:
[Context](http://www.pic-upload.de/view-23483711/context.png.html)

Comment: Please add the `pom.xml` for server and client parts to the question.

Comment: pom.xml is added. But what do you mean with client parts?

Comment: You added the `pom.xml` of the GlassFish Admin Console...I mean the `pom.xml` of your project (Right-click the project -> Open POM). The client part is the one with the `main` method.

Comment: Sorry I don't find it. It is a javaEE EnterpriseApplication. In Netbeans and in Windows Explorer I can't find any pom.xml. And my context-menu doesn't proivde any "open pom". I added two new screenshots.

Comment: Ah, I see this aren't Maven projects. Which libraries are you packaging with your client app?

Comment: By default I use Java EE 6 and 7 API Library and JDK 1.8. On client-side (in project (adding numbers) I additioanly added gf-client.jar from glassfish and the folder "modules" from glassfish

Comment: Hmm, I can't see any real problem with your setup. Maybe if you set the ant verbosity level to debug (Settings button in the ant output window) the debug log gives any hint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55327/discussion-between-j0chn-and-unwichtich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem:

> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is
>   not native or abstract in class file javax/resource/ResourceException

seems to be caused by the order in which the `Java EE 6 API Library` and the `gf-client.jar` are added to the classpath.

It seems to be important that the `gf-client.jar` is the first library in the classpath.

To fix the issue, change the order of the libraries by removing `Java EE 6 API Library` and adding it again, so that `gf-client.jar` is on the first position.

Make sure to `Clean & Build` your project before you run it again.

**See also:**

- [EJB 3.1 | Error calling remote session bean via JNDI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8201662/ejb-3-1-error-calling-remote-session-bean-via-jndi)
- [java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/PersistenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559336/java-lang-classformaterror-absent-code-attribute-in-method-that-is-not-native-o)